# module 'keras.api._v2.keras' has no attribute 'model'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, module, neural-network

I tried to create a nueral network by:

`import tensorflow as tf`

`from tensorflow import keras`

`model = keras.model.Sequential([`

```
keras.layers.Flatten(), # the input layer... why it has no size???
keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = 'relu'), #the hidden
keras.layers.Dense(10) #The output layer
```

`])`

But it yeild at me:

**module 'keras.api._v2.keras' has no attribute 'model'**

Here is the tensorflow package info:

Name: tensorflow

Version: 2.8.0

Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.

Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/

Author: Google Inc.

Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org

License: Apache 2.0

Location: c:\users\lior\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages

Requires: absl-py, astunparse, flatbuffers, gast, google-pasta, grpcio, h5py, keras, keras-preprocessing, libclang, numpy, opt-einsum, protobuf, setuptools, six, tensorboard, tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, termcolor, tf-estimator-nightly, typing-extensions, wrapt

Required-by:

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the `keras.model` call. It should be instead:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
```

The `.dir` command was very helpful to me to find this problem.